# How to set background pages for multiple pages in one stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I want my stylesheet to control the background image of each page, being able to use a different background for each page.

Answer (score 1):

You can give every `body` element an `id`. Then you can customize your CSS with multiple id selectors:

```
body#index-page { 
  background: red;
}

body#about-us { 
  background: blue; 
}
```

Comment: thanks! im very new to html/css!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with css that you would place in the head of each of those pages.

In a manner of:

```
<head>
     ...
     <style type="text/css">
          body {background: url(path to page specific bg image);}
     </style>
</head>
```

This css would overcome the general one from the stylesheet and you would have a different bg for each page as specified.

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks also now i know two ways!